# Verify a string is valid as an XML attribute value

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Given a string, I need to determine if it is valid as an attribute value in XML.

According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-AttValue), the following three characters are not allowed:

```
<
& (unless used to encode a disallowed character, such as "&amp;")
" or ' (whichever is not used to wrap the value is allowed)
```

My tests indicate that creating an XAttribute object with a value containing any of these characters seems to be valid (I expected an exception, but nothing was thrown).

Is there a way to check that a given string is valid as a value for an XML attribute (other than manually checking for these characters)?

Comment: Using `XAttribute` will escape these for you.

Comment: I've answered the question that was asked, but it would be useful to know *why* you were trying to do this.

Comment: It's a field that in most use cases will end up being stuck into XML eventually. We wanted to try to do the validation when the field was set rather than when it's put into XML. If XAttribute will just encode it for us, then this becomes kind of a non-issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My tests indicate that creating an XAttribute object with a value containing any of these characters seems to be valid

Yes, because they will be escaped appropriately. For example:

```
XElement element = new XElement("Foo",
   new XAttribute("name", "Jon & Holly"));
Console.WriteLine(element);
```

prints out:

```
<Foo name="Jon &amp; Holly" />
```

The *logical* content of the attribute is `"Jon & Holly"` but the representation in the text of the XML file is `"Jon &amp; Holly"`.

If you want to check for validity in *representation* form, you could always use:

```
string text = "<x y=\"" + value + "\" />";
try
{
    XElement.Parse(text);
    // TODO: Check that there's only one attribute in the result...
}
catch (XmlException e) { /* Invalid */ }
```

That's pretty horrible though - are you *sure* you really need to do this?